# What are the best dimensions for responsive web designs

Tags: html, css, responsive

Searching through internet I found many different dimensions called proper in order to create responsive designs but I  am looking for the best breakpoints specially when it comes to mobiles with small screens such as j510 (j5 2016)

Comment: Hey, while I know it might be hard to find the right responsive dimensions, this question is irrelevant, as you can easily figure out what works best with some experimentation, so here's how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask However, I still want to give you my help , so I recomend max-width : 600 for mobile, max-width : 800 for tablet, max-width: 1100 for a laptop and max width : 1500 for a well sized desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real answer... it depends on your site, design, target.

I usually use these media queries and it is working 99% of the time:

```css
/* for-phone-only */
@media (max-width: 599px) { }


/* for-tablet-portrait-up */
@media (min-width: 600px) { }


/* for-tablet-landscape-up */
@media (min-width: 900px) { }


/* for-desktop-up */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { }


/* for-medium-desktop-up */
@media (min-width: 1400px) { }


/* for-big-desktop-up */
@media (min-width: 1800px) { }
```

*Caution: the media queries are mobile-first*

Answer (score 1):

I generally use `max-width: 767px` for mobile, `768px to 1365px` for tablet and above that is desktop.